# How is nullable type implemented by .NET?

Tags: .net, nullable

How is nullable type implemented by .NET ?

```
Nullable<int> x = 5;
int? x = 5;
```

Comment: @JonSkeet, I looked at the duplicate question.
If Nullable<T> is a struct. Being a struct it is value type, then how come we are able to assign "null" to its instace ? int? = null

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is the same in .net

```
int? variable = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

So a `Nullable<t>` has two main properties: `value` and `hasValue`

Now if you have a value type (such as an int) - it can never have a null value, in the case of an int it would have an initial value of 0.

Since however `value` is a property, you can keep track separately of whether it's set to null or not, and if it's null yet you try to use the getter method of the `value` property, it can throw an exception.